# Find number of characters remaining on uitextview after selecting text and tap Cut

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a uitextview. I have some text on it. I have a counter at the bottom right corner. 80 characters is the limit. 35 characters exist in the uitextview. If i select 5 characters and tap cut the counter at the bottom right shows 34/80 because i remove one character each time the user taps backspace. Is it possible to find the number of characters removed when user taps Cut and then update the counter to be 30/80?

Comment: Conform your class to `UITextViewDelegate` and implement `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView { }`

Comment: Great it worked! Thank a lot Mr. DonMag! If you want add it as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conform your class to `UITextViewDelegate` and implement

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView { 
    // update your counter here
}
```